# Portfiolio Category filter Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filter, portfolio

I am building a Wordpress Portfolio with Quicksand filtering functionality.

The part I need help with is that I have about 20 categories and would like to split them into 3 rows, each with their own title - Sound, Design and Video.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
            <?php  
                 $terms = get_terms("tagportfolio");  
                 $count = count($terms);  
                 echo '<ul id="portfolio-filter">';  
                 echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';  
                 if ( $count > 0 ){  
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  
                            $termname = strtolower($term->name);  
                            $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);  
                            echo '<li><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';  
                        }  
                 }  
                 echo "</ul>";  
            ?>
```

Comment: You'll have to add some more information how the categories are linked to the subcategories

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, "tagportfolio" is a custom, chierarchical taxonomy?

Than use:

```
<?php get_term_children( $ID_of_subcategory, 'tagportfolio') ?>
```

to get elements from $ID_of_subcategory.